# Add two Decimal Values and Convert the Final value to INT

Tags: c#, int, type-conversion, decimal

i am adding two decimal values like

```
decimal one=0; decimal two=0; decimal sum=0;
sum = one+ two;
Int final =0;
```

example

```
sum = 1.2 + 2.2;
sum = 3.4;
```

Now i want to save this 3.4 in Integer Final by neglecting that decimal part (.4). How can I do this?

Comment: Have you tried anything? just assign the result to an `int`. decimal point will be truncated

Comment: Thanks for reply

Answer (score 1):

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            decimal one = 1.4M; decimal two = 3.4M; decimal sum = 0;
            sum = one + two;
            Int32 final = (Int32)(sum);
            Int32 roundfinal = (Int32)(Math.Round(sum));
            Console.WriteLine("final is "+ final);
            Console.WriteLine("roundfinal is " + roundfinal);
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
```

check the answer without round rumber and with round number 4.8 is 4 without round and 4.8 round is 5

Comment: This is the Answer Thanks for reply this helped me

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for!:

`final = Convert.ToInt32(sum);`

**Or:**

`final = (int)sum;`

Answer (score 0):

```
Decimal value = Decimal.Add(a1, a2);
FinalOutout int = Convert.ToInt32(value);
```

It will work.